# Start a project

Tags: android, react-native

Occurred some errors while I was starting to make a project.
I just installed all packages. tried to create new project. it is my first time to work with react-native.

what's wrong? what should I do?

```
This will walk you through creating a new React Native project in /TestApp
Installing react-native...
Consider installing yarn to make this faster: https://yarnpkg.com
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN Found: react@undefined
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"18.1.0" from react-native@0.70.6
npm WARN node_modules/react-native
npm WARN   react-native@"*" from the root project
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN Found: react@undefined
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^16.0.0 || ^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0" from react-shallow-renderer@16.15.0
npm WARN node_modules/react-native/node_modules/react-shallow-renderer
npm WARN   react-shallow-renderer@"^16.15.0" from react-native@0.70.6
npm WARN   node_modules/react-native
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN Found: react@undefined
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0" from use-sync-external-store@1.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react-native/node_modules/use-sync-external-store
npm WARN   use-sync-external-store@"^1.0.0" from react-native@0.70.6
npm WARN   node_modules/react-native
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN Found: @babel/preset-env@undefined
npm WARN node_modules/@babel/preset-env
npm WARN 
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer @babel/preset-env@"^7.1.6" from jscodeshift@0.13.1
npm WARN node_modules/jscodeshift
npm WARN   jscodeshift@"^0.13.1" from react-native-codegen@0.70.6
npm WARN   node_modules/react-native-codegen
npm ERR! code FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! errno FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! invalid json response body at https://registry.npmjs.org/react reason: Unexpected end of JSON input

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-11-27T19_45_05_880Z-debug.log
Error: Command failed: npm install --save --save-exact react-native
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:635:11)
    at execSync (child_process.js:671:15)
    at run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:294:5)
    at createProject (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:249:3)
    at init (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:200:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:153:7)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14) {
  status: 1,
  signal: null,
  output: [ null, null, null ],
  pid: 45745,
  stdout: null,
  stderr: null
}
Command `npm install --save --save-exact react-native` failed.
```

This is my OS information:

```
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 11
KDE Plasma Version: 5.20.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.78.0
Qt Version: 5.15.2
Kernel Version: 5.10.0-19-amd64
```

I install all requirments.
I need Terminal Commands what i should to do.

I would be appreciated you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using expo. https://docs.expo.dev/get-started/create-a-new-app/
Expo, in my opinion, does a better job than react-native walking through new users on how to use react-native.

run `npx create-expo-app my-app` this will create a new app called "my-app".

Or you could run `npx create-expo-app --template` to begin with a starter app. I like to use 'Navigation (TypeScript)'.

The expo link will explain how to set up your app and how to run your app in a simulator or with the expo go app on your phone. It's a great resource. There is also a tutorial that explains in depth how to create, style, and build an app using react-native.

Hope that helped!

Comment: I received this error:
`✖ Something went wrong installing JavaScript dependencies. Check your npm logs. Continuing to create the app.`
and then when I wanna run `npm run android`
I get another error: `> my-app@1.0.0 android
> expo start --android

sh: 1: expo: not found`